# RegExp. Странное поведение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пробую два выражения:

```
"xy".match(/x?/)    # -> ["x"]
"xy".match(/y?/)    # -> [""]
```

Почему так происходит? Я имею ввиду `x` находит, а `y` - нет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так работает механизм регулярных выражений.

По умолчанию регулярное выражение будет искать самое первое совпадение, после чего развивать его на максимальную длину.

В первом случае вы ищете символ `x` или пустую строку. Первый символ строки равен `x`. совпадение максимально возможное, поэтому возвращается `["x"]`

Во втором случае вы ищете символ `y` или пустую строку. Символа `y` на первой позиции строки нет, но пустая строка нашлась. За счёт этого считаем, что совпадение найдено, и возвращаем `[""]`, т. е. пустую строку.

Comment: Т.е. чтоб найти `y` - надо добавить флаг `g`?

Comment: `По умолчанию регулярное выражение будет искать самое первое совпадение, после чего развивать его на максимальную длину.
`  Юр секонд паряgraph ис wrong. Оп файлс то осе тхэ глобал модифир.

Comment: @Decode да, параметр `g` решит эту проблему. Он найдёт все совпадения, в том числе и пустые строки: `"xy".match(/y?/g); // -> ["", "y", ""]`. Так что стоит подумать над тем, какие цели преследуются и какое регулярное выражение использовать

Answer (score 3):

`х?` соответствует опциональной х и `y` соответствует опциональной у. Функция, которую Вы используете, чтобы соотнести строку ввода (`match`), указана без глобального модификатора `G`. Без него функция вернет только первое совпадение.

```
 "ху".match(/х?/)
```

`x` является первым символом, соответствующим этому регулярному выражению `х?`.

```
 "ху".match(/y?/)
```

Здесь также первая буква x. Так как вы сделали регулярное выражение `y` в качестве дополнения, то соответствием будет пустая строка, которая существует перед каждым несоответствующим символом. Таким образом, это будет соответствовать пустой строке, которая существует до первого `x`. В итоге, Вы получили пустую строку на выходе.

[под] (Я не знаю, русский язык .. использовал переводчик Google .. :-))

Comment: черт, как это мило =D

Comment: yep, regex is an awesome chapter..

Comment: @AvinashRaj i'm said "мило" not about regexp, it's about trying to help by using absolutely unfamiliar language =)